# ¿Como soluciono error "was not declared in this scope" en mi codigo de arduino ide?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Buenas tardes soy novato en la programacion y me estoy adentrando al tema, inetente arreglarlo por mi cuenta y no puedo con ello, ya intente de varias maneras y no puedo correguir el error

Tengo que armar un circuito (lo cual ya hice) para sensar temperatura y humedad con esp8266 para que mande inforMacion de temperatura y humedad a una direcion de red local, pero al momento de compilar mi codigo me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTA LINEA ES LA DEL ERROR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AQUI DEJO PARTE DE MI CODIGO;

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "DHT.h"

// Uncomment one of the lines below for whatever DHT sensor type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321

/*Put your SSID & Password*/
const char* ssid = "INFINITUM3108_2.4";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "++++++++";  //Enter Password here

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

// DHT Sensor
uint8_t DHTPin = D8; 
               
// Initialize DHT sensor.
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);                

float Temperature;
float Humidity;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);
  
  pinMode(DHTPin, INPUT);

  dht.begin();              

  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  //connect to your local wi-fi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  //check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}
void loop() {
  
  server.handleClient();
  
}

void handle_OnConnect() {

 Temperature = dht.readTemperature(); // Gets the values of the temperature
  Humidity = dht.readHumidity(); // Gets the values of the humidity 
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(Temperature,Humidity)); 
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ESP8266 != Arduino**

Los nombre D1, D2, etc están definidos para los Arduinos, pero no para los ESP8266/ESP32. Esto es porque Arduino fue diseñado como un todo (CPU + Placa), mientras que los ESP8266 son sólo la CPU, que puede ser usada como accesorio de un Arduino o montada en su propia placa (Wemos, NodeMCU, etc.).

Para manejar los pines de un ESP8266, primero tienes que mirar el pinout de la placa:

[image: Pinout Wemos]

y fijarte el número de GPIO asociado al pin en cuestión. El número del GPIO es el valor que tienes que usar como pin.

En tu caso, la línea de data del DHT11 está conecta a D8, y si miras el pinout, corresponde a GPIO15. Esto es válido para placas Wemos y nodeMCU. Para otras placas, busca el pinout correspondiente.

La declaración queda así:

```
// DHT Sensor
uint8_t DHTPin = 15;
```